# Tableau: last value calculation in calculated field

Tags: tableau-api, calculated-field

my dataset is like this

```
KPI                    VALUE    TYPE     DATE  
coffee break duration   11        0      30/06/2015  
coffee break duration   12        0      31/07/2015  
coffee break duration   10        0      30/11/2014  
coffee break duration   10        0      31/12/2014  
coffee expense          20        1      31/07/2015  
coffee expense          20        1      31/12/2014  
coffee consumers        15       -1      31/07/2015  
coffee consumers        17       -1      31/12/2014
```

for Type, 0 means minutes, 1 means dollars and -1 means people

I want to get a table like this

```
KPI                     Year(date)    YTD  
coffee break duration    2015         11,5  
coffee break duration    2014         10  
....
```

YTD calculation is:

if sum([TYPE]) = 0 then avg([VALUE])
 
elseif sum([TYPE]) > 0 then sum([VALUE])
elseif sum([TYPE]) < 0 then [**last value for the considered year**]
end

By [**Last value for the considered year**] I mean the last entry available, in a year if my table is set to Year, otherwise it has to change dynamically based on what Timespan I want to show.

What can I do to have [**last value for the considered year**] as a calc field ready to use in my YTD calc?

Many thanks,
Stefania

Comment: Create a new calculated field IF MAX(DATE) THEN VALUE. Place this Calculated Field in your if statement

Comment: @FirebladeDan "the calculation contains error: expected type boolean, found date. Comparison in 'IF' expression must be boolean type."

Comment: WINDOW_MAX(IF DATE = MAX(DATE) THEN VALUE)... Right click this pill and group by date or something of that nature. I would have to look at your workbook :/

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your question, than you can use LOD in the IF statement

```
if sum(type) = 0 then avg([value])
elseif sum([type]) > 0 then sum(value)
elseif sum([type]) < 0 then max(if [date] = { INCLUDE kpi: max(date)} then [value] end)
end
```

If there are several values on the last day of the considered year, it would take the biggest value

I slightly modified your data to show that results are working correctly
[image]